# User Lower Function in where condition in searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick

@ankane 
How can i use postgres lower function in searchkick's where condition

I have below query which is working fine

```
klass.search(@params[:query], fields: [:name,:category_name],where: {or: [[{available_cities_name: "New Yo"},{available_cities_short_name: "NY"}]]}).hits
```

Now i want to use lower function but i am getting syntax error

```
klass.search(@params[:query],
  fields: [:name,:category_name],
  where: {
    or: [ [
      {"lower(available_cities_name) = ?", "New Yo"},
      {"lower(available_cities_short_name) = ?", "ny"}
    ]]
  }
).hits
```

I am getting below syntax error,

> SyntaxError: unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input
>   e_cities_name) = ?", "New Yo"},{"lower(available_cities_shor

Can somebody tell me how to use lower function in searchkick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch does not have a `lower` function. To get around this, you can index a lowercase version of the field and query against that.

```
def search_data
  {
    available_cities_name: available_cities_name,
    available_cities_name_lower: available_cities_name.downcase
  }
end
```

Comment: Accepting your answer without testing it, because i know you are genius :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to pass args to part of your query. The first is to use hash-syntax eg: `{arg_name: 'expected_value'}` and the second is array-syntax: `["arg_name = ?", 'expected_value']`

Your bug is that you are using array-syntax, but trying to pass it as a hash. ie: `{"arg_name = ?", 'expected_value'}` which is invalid syntax.

Instead try:

```
klass.search(@params[:query],
   fields: [:name,:category_name],
   where: {
     or: [
       ["lower(available_cities_name) = ?", "New Yo"],
       ["lower(available_cities_short_name) = ?", "ny"]
     ]
   }
 ).hits
```

or even just:

```
klass.search(@params[:query],
   fields: [:name,:category_name],
   where: ["lower(available_cities_name) = ? OR lower(available_cities_short_name) = ?", "New Yo", "ny"]
 ).hits
```

(Note: all code needs to be bug-tested before running).

Comment: let me try your solution

Comment: Yes you are right. i used array syntax. but i think it is not working properly. as i have `city_name = New York `and `city short name = ny` but when i try this query it is giving me the same result  `klass.search(@params[:query],fields: [:name,:category_name],where: ["lower(available_cities_name) = ? OR lower(available_cities_short_name) = ?", "vzxzjx", "czbchjzx"]).hits` instead it should not result any product

Comment: same results for this query also `klass.search(@params[:query],fields: [:name,:category_name],where: ["lower(available_cities_name) = ? OR lower(available_cities_short_name) = ?", "", ""]).hits`

Comment: You have got past the syntax error though right? this other thing you're trying to squeeze into comments is probably best written as a new Question ;)

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your suggestion. i resolved issue from my side. so no need to create new question. thanks for your time and answer :)

Comment: You resolved the syntax, but it is not worth, because query is not correct and i didn't get proper output which i want. i can accept and upvote it. but it will mislead other users thinking that this query is correct. sorry !!!

Comment: It solved the actual problem that you had and that you asked for help with. if you then went on to solve another problem in the same code... that's a different question. with a different answer.

Comment: Can somebody tell me how to use lower function in searchkick ? that's my question, check it. and still i don't know how to use it